# firefox proxy settings

Tags: proxy, torify

I want to connect to the Tor network using firefox, I installed tor via apt and it's running on port 9001, so I set mozzila proxy settings for http on 127.0.0.1:9001 but I cannot get the connexion "because of proxy settings", 
I tried the same settings with socks4/5 (really no idea what this is) and also the option "remote dns" but nothing will do. What is going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tor's default SOCKS port is 9050 as far as I remember, so try to use it **With** remote DNS option.

Comment: Thanks, I would like to know also why my router shows to be directly connected to the Tor relays while I'm behind a vpn.

Comment: VPN is just a transport layer, so if your Tor reaches the outer network(including Tor network) via VPN - it's just like a wire plug to him, nothing unnatural. Post your VPN scheme details and I'll be able to point you to exact mechanism of how it works in your particular case

Comment: I could not get to recreate the issue of yersterday, now it seems fine (maybe I needed to reboot after installing tor ?) So this a screenshot of internet sockets and routes after I'm connected to a website; also a dig on the vpn destination that gateways to my router, and my vpn .conf file. http://pasteboard.co/1B7bxQUBS.png

Comment: It seems that you're using VPN to reach outer network not just for Tor, so first "layer of the pipe" is your VPN connection. After that - here goes the Tor, reaching outer world via your VPN too, and after that you're using Tor to do your things. After installing tor there's no need in rebooting: it does not use neither the registry in windows, nor any system-wide overlays/ld-preloads on Linux.

Comment: I think having my router connected to the tor relays came from the fact that tor is launched before openvpn as a startup service, because when my PC starts a netstat shows this flaw, but when I deactivate/reactivate Tor, it moves behind the vpn. Just have to configure the launch order now...

Comment: Yes, and I recommend you to alter openvpn scripts for up and down to down tor *before* shutting down VPN and start tor *after* the connection is established(you can make it in openvpn config). Don't forget to use TLSKey in your OpenVPN!

Comment: I've come up with a little script but i'm not sure where to implement it since putting it after up / down in the openvpn.conf file has no effects. Thanks. http://pasteboard.co/gPNH6MnO5.png